# How do maven finds the authentication defined in settings.xml?

Tags: maven

I want to deploy my jar files to Maven Central and GitHub Packages, the usernames and passwords are declared as the following format in `/path/to/maven/conf/settings.xml`:

```xml
    <server>
      <id>snapshot</id>
      <username>${my-maven-central-username}</username>
      <password>${my-maven-central-password}</password>
    </server>
    <server>
      <id>maven-central</id>
      <username>${my-maven-central-username}</username>
      <password>${my-maven-central-password}</password>
    </server>
    <server>
      <id>GitHub</id>
      <username>${my-github-username}</username>
      <password>${my-github-token}</password>
    </server>
```

And in `pom.xml` file of the project, I declared 3 profiles: maven, GitHub and local.

```xml
        <profile>
            <id>maven</id>
            <!-- build tag here -->
            <distributionManagement>
                <snapshotRepository>
                    <id>snapshot</id>
                    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
                </snapshotRepository>
                <repository>
                    <id>maven-central</id>
                    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/</url>
                </repository>
            </distributionManagement>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>github</id>
            <!-- build tag here -->
            <distributionManagement>
                <repository>
                    <id>github</id>
                    <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/${my_github_package_uri}</url>
                </repository>
            </distributionManagement>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <!-- build tag here -->
        </profile>
```

For now, I always gets a 401 from github and maven central. How do maven find username and password when deploy and how to let maven use correct username and password?

Comment: The `id` in your profile for example `<id>maven</id>` must be equal to the `<id>..</id>` in your `settings.xml` and the server entry you would like to use... and also the id must be exactly the same ... there are differences in case for example for `github` vs. `GitHub`...